# xrandr says 'HDMI-1' and not 'DP-1' - why?

Tags: xrandr, intel-graphics

This is a Dell system with Intel HD4600 onboard graphics.  It has 2 physical DisplayPorts and a single physical VGA port; it has NO physical HDMI ports.

As part of trying to set up a 4K TV, I noticed that having used a Displayport/HDMI cable/converter, `xrandr` claims that `HDMI-1` is connected but `DP-1` is disconnected.  Should I be using `xrandr` to disable `HDMI-1` and enable `DP-1` or is this just how things work when using a DisplayPort/HDMI adapter?

BTW, "if it ain't broke..." doesn't apply here as I've not yet managed to get 4k out of this system :-(.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that because the TV only has an HDMI input, the DisplayPort adapter falls back to HDMI mode and creates a virtual 'HDMI' port to reflect this.

The answer to my 4k issue was also that the graphics chipset only supports 4k/24Hz (not 4k/50Hz or 4k/60Hz); the key piece of info is that in HDMI mode the chipset only supports HDMI 1.4 which cannnot support the higher refresh rates.

Using `cvt` and `xrandr` to create/set a 4k/24Hz set up worked a treat.